Unable to update from 22.04.4 LTS
Running Ubuntu 22.04.04 LTS, 64-bit, with GNOME 42.9. I get a message that there are updates, including Ubuntu, but I cannot download the updates. It's not clear to me what the options are or which I should choose under any of the tabs in Settings/Software & Updates. Any advice on what to choose or where to get more information?

Personally, I find it easier to just open terminal and run commands from there (as the GUI options tend to show only partial messages, where as at terminal you can see them all, or limit them too if required).  I'd open terminal, then run sudo apt update and read that output, looking for any warnings, errors and all details is there (ie. nothing missing).  Assuming that was clean I'd then run sudo apt full-upgrade to apply all upgrades; again scanning messages for any issues/problems and letting it run... I'd expect to have clues from here... (if there were problems)

This question is similar to: Upgrade to new version. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
